# QGIS and arcmap compatibility in image georeferencing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, georeferencing

I have georeferenced an image in QGIS but when I imported it to arcmap 10.0 it saying "In consistent extent". Any one know how to solve it?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136460/ but I'm not quite sure because of the 'inconsistent extent' error being thrown. My first question would be is there a world file for the image, or is it a valid geotiff (in which case location information would be stored in the header of the tiff)? If the georeferencing is only internal, ArcGIS would have no idea what information QGIS supplied.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to check the Spatial Reference of your image. If there is no spatial reference set for your image, try to define its spatial reference.

Right-click at your data layer which you want to check its spatial reference. Go to "Source" tab. Scroll down on the Properties box, you will find Spatial Reference section. If your data has spatial reference set for it, then there will be an information about what spatial reference it uses.