# QGIS world files rather than .xml

Tags: qgis, raster

Is there a way to get QGIS to write out a world file (.wld/.pgw/.jpw) etc rather than an aux.xml.
I see the aux.xml is in general better but it isn't supported by the other software I am using. 
I can manually write the .wld based on the aux.xml but that is a bit of a faff.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to generate world files for raster X?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14545/how-to-generate-world-files-for-raster-x)

Comment: I did look before asking. The answer is best put here http://linfiniti.com/2011/08/extract-projection-tool-for-qgis/. Or Toolbox>Extract Projection