# Generate world file from PyQgis Print composer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

I've managed to save Qgis print composer maps by looking at the example below:

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/composer.html#output-to-a-raster-image

But how can I save a world file along with the raster image from PyQgis?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to generate world files for raster X?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14545/how-to-generate-world-files-for-raster-x)